# Question on Weierstrass $\wp$ function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

I omitted the proof of Lemma 1.5

In remark, how do we conclude from lemma 1.5 that the given series converges uniformly? Don't we only know the point-wise convergence (with fixed $\tau$) of the series?

The below argument seems to show how to use Lemma 1.5 to conclude that Weierstrass $\wp$ function has double poles at lattices, but I'm really lost what's happening here. Could you explain what Stein is doing here, or suggest any relevant concept/theorem to understand this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{z^2}+\sum_{n,m\ne (0,0)} \frac1{(z+n+m\tau)^2}-\frac1{(n+m\tau)^2}=\frac1{z^2}+\sum_{n,m\ne (0,0)} \frac{-z^2-2z(n+m\tau)}{(n+m\tau)^2(z+n+m\tau)^2}$$ converges locally uniformly on $\Bbb{C-(Z+Z\tau)}$ thus it is analytic there.

Moreover removing one term of the series gives that the series for $\wp(z)-\frac1{(z-a-b\tau)^2}$ converges uniformly and is analytic on a disk around $a+b\tau$.

Comment: Sorry it's way over my head and I don't quite understand. Could you please explain a bit more? I know the definition of local uniform convergence and analyticity but what theorem do you use to conclude that? And can you explain a bit about the next sentence as well?

Comment: It is Morera theorem. But it is mostly obvious that it is holomorphic with derivative the series of the derivatives.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand what it's getting at

Comment: What is your question exactly ?